# Como tipar e manipular array de objetos em typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Bom dia, estou estudando typescript e estou com o seguinte erro:

Inicialmente a intenção desse exemplo é criar uma função que recebe um array de objetos e retorna o nome dos alunos aprovados, obs: coloquei o retorno da função como boolean porque na lógica atual está retornando um array com boolean e strings, mas o problema maior é a mensagem de erro

```
A propriedade '**nota**' e '**name**' não existe no tipo '**object**'
```

segue abaixo o exemplo:

```
 const students: Array<object> = [
  { name: 'Carla', nota: 6 },
  { name: 'Fernando', nota: 5 },
  { name: 'Ana',  nota: 7 },
  { name: 'Denis', nota: 8 },
  { name: 'Alice', nota: 9 },
  { name: 'Antonio', nota: 9 }
]

const aprovados = (lista: Array<object>): Array<boolean | string> => {
  return lista.map((index) => (index.nota >= 7) && `${index.name}`)
}
console.log(aprovados(students));
```

Queria saber como poderia ficar a tipagem desse index

Comment: Bem simples, no lugar de **<object>** vc pode passar uma **`interface`**, um **`type`** ou até mesmo uma **`classe`** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar uma `interface` e definir os subtipos do objeto em questão, por exemplo:

```
interface Alunos {
  name: string;
  nota: number;
}

const alunos: Array<Alunos> = [
  { name: 'Carla', nota: 6 },
  { name: 'Fernando', nota: 5 },
  { name: 'Ana',  nota: 7 },
  { name: 'Denis', nota: 8 },
  { name: 'Alice', nota: 9 },
  { name: 'Antonio', nota: 9 }
]
```

Já para explicar o porque do retorno da sua função está vindo como `boolean` ou `string`, primeiro você deve entender como funciona o método `.map()`:

> O método `map()` invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.

Ou seja, no seu código `map` está passando por cada item de `lista` e retornando um array onde cada item desse array é o respectivo retorno da sua função de callback passada como argumento para `map()`:

```
(index.nota >= 7) && `${index.name}`
```

O javascript avalia sua expressão da esquerda para a direita, logo ele sempre avalia `(index.nota >= 7)` e se essa condição for `true` ele segue avaliando a segunda expressão, que no seu caso você está simplesmente retornando uma `string`. Ou seja, o retorno da sua função é um array composto por `boolean` (porque se a primeira expressão retornar `false`, ele vai adicionar `false` como um item do array de retorno, e ele não avalia a segunda expressão) ou `string` (porque se a primeira expressão retornar `true` ele segue lendo o código e retorna a `string` `index.name`, adicionando uma `string` ao array de retorno). Ou seja seu retorno virou um mix entre `boolean` e `string`, por isso o TypeScript avaliou automaticamente o retorno da sua função como um array de `boolean` ou `string`.

Outra coisa que observei no seu código, é que para o que você descreveu, o correto não é utilizar o método `map()` e sim o método `filter()`.

Na sua função você deseja filtrar somente os alunos que possuem nota inferior ou igual à 7, logo utilizar o método `map()` não vai funcionar, pois ele retorna todos os itens do array, você deve utilizar o método `filter()`, para filtrar somente os ítens do array que você deseja, no seu caso, os itens que possuam a pripriedade `nota` maior ou igual à 7.

```
const alunosAprovados = alunos.filter((index) => (index.nota >= 7));
```

Veja no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBsCuID2BnZAbwChlkQ4BbCALmTzClAHMBuU8nMOOkTSgEbR2AX2LEEOEA2RwsuPHVRQocAJ4AeDNnwA+ZAF5kAbQ6FyVWsgDkAYThR0cawBpO3OgDZkIl2YvUdNYAYtAUIAAmOK7uPMgArD5+ZOYUgTaoFDGxdADsSf5pVtYAIhAgwHgxuB7IABwFKQHFGMBI1VxxAJyNRM1BmWBSwNFuNd0+xAC64pLSYLLy+KgADlA4AG5wUQRGcjp4AHQwwOiQUAAUF6AREAAeAJSG+teR94fjyLpGuQ8Ps1I8Dh0BBDugcMwLvsFKt1lsdg9WEA) funcionando.

Abaixo eu deixo os links da documentação para melhor entendimento do que foi dito:

`.map()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

`.filter()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

`interface` -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: realmente com o filter atende muito bem ao problema, muito obrigado pelos ensinamentos e pela resposta.